# PHPstorm: Unresolved variable or type with ExtJs alternateClassName declaration

Tags: javascript, extjs, phpstorm

I have a ExtJs class that is defined like :

```
Ext.define('Mb.lang.Lang', {
    alternateClassName: 'Lang',
```

As it can be expected, PHPstorm does not recognize the class name `Lang` in the code and shows everywhere the error

> Unresolved variable or type Lang

Reading other questions, I think I could address this using PHPdoc blocks, but I don't really know how. Can you suggest a solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution finally proved to be simple:
I had to use the `@alias` of JsDoc.

```
/**
 * @alias Lang
 */
Ext.define('Mb.lang.Lang', {
    alternateClassName: 'Lang',
```